# What is mean rank?

Tags: spss, descriptive-statistics, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I am a student and I am doing a project that consists of calculating Mann Whitney U test. I would like to know the definition of mean rank that is calculated with this analysis. Also, I would like to know what is the difference between median and mean rank?

Answer (score 4):

Given a column of data that looks like this:

```
20
23
21
25
20
```

You need to rank the column smallest to largest and then calculate rank by noting the position in a second column:

```
20  1.5
20  1.5
21  3
23  4
25  5
```

If the data have ties (like the two 20s here in first and second place), averaged position is used.

Mean rank will be the arithmetic average of the positions in the list: $$\frac{1.5+1.5+3+4+5}{5}=3$$

When there is an odd number of rows, the median will be the middle value of the *original* data after it is ranked. If there is an even number of rows, you take the average of the two values in the middle. Here the median is 21.

The *median rank* will be the same calculation, but for the column noting the position. Here it is 3, same as the mean.

Usually, the mean rank and the median rank will be different.

Comment: priviet Dmittriy, I am using SPSS to calculate Mann Whitney, how would I understand if I should use median or mean rank for my analysis?

Comment: I don't know anything about SPSS, and in any case, this kind of software questions is off-topic here. The U test typically uses [the sum of the ranks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#Calculations). There is a related test that groups observations in each group depending on where they lie relative to the overall rank median, though it tests a different hypothesis. Perhaps you can clarify which one you have in mind by editing your question.

Comment: Looks like SPSS does [something else](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/mann-whitney-u-test-using-spss-statistics.php). If the two distributions have the same shape, use the the median version. If they don't, you should compare mean ranks. You can make histograms or use a qq-plot to determine with your data.

Comment: I can confirm this, in SPSS, always check the shape of the distribution, and use the mean only if the shapes are different.

Comment: My question is - while using Mann Whitney test, we have two measures of central tendencies to pick - either mean rank or median: https://www.sheffield.ac.uk/polopoly_fs/1.714563!/file/stcp-karadimitriou-MannWhitR.pdf
what is the logic here of picking mean rank or median? I don't agree with the answer that SPSS checks the distribution before reporting means. This is a default feature of SPSS to report mean ranks. We need to separately check the curves to confirm the homogeneity.

Comment: Please take a look at my response in the comment above.

Comment: I did, but my question is now about the logic of when to use mean rank and median for mann whitney

Comment: I have answered your original question, and have suggested what you need to check to decide which test to use. If something is not clear there, I am not sure how else to explain it. If you have additional, new questions, please start a separate question.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. You have also provided the definition of median rank with the above example. How can I calculate the median rank for two distributions where few of the numbers are same?

Comment: It's exactly the procedure outlined in the answer: middle rank if you have an odd number of observations, and an average of the middle two if even.

Comment: *"Usually, the mean rank and the median rank will be different."* Isn't this only the case when there is a tie around the median?

Answer (score 0):

When using the Mann-Whitney U test, if two population samples have similar shapes the result of the test can be used to infer whether two population medians differ or not. But when the shapes are different, the result only indicates whether the mean rank of two populations varies.